# pandas plotting skipping xtick labels

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to display two pandas Series objects together, which works, except all the labels are not displayed.

I am trying to plot the two Series together like this:

```
plt.figure()
sns.set_style('ticks')
ts86['Gene'].value_counts().plot(kind='area')
l97['Gene'].value_counts().plot(kind='area')
sns.despine(offset=10)
```

But only one of the indexes is displayed.

[image]

Here are the two Series that I have:

`one`

```
TIIIh     25
TET2-2    24
IDH2      15
TIIIa     14
TIIIb     12
TIIIj     11
TIIIp      9
p53-1      9
SF3B1      8
TIIIe      8
KRAS-1     7
TIIIo      6
TIIId      6
TET2-1     6
GATA1      5
p53-3      5
HRAS       5
NRAS-2     4
IDH1       4
TIIIq      4
JAK2       4
TIIIc      4
TIIIf      3
TIIIg      3
TIIIm      3
KRAS-2     3
p53-2      3
TIIIk      3
TIIIn      2
DNMT3a     1
```

and

`two`

```
p53-1     17
p53-2      2
NRAS-2     2
p53-3      1
KRAS-2     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output graph shows `value_counts` of 2 dataframes but obviously the index orders are no longer the same, so there is no way to show xticks at this point (e.g. highest count in df1 is `TIIIh` while that of df2 is `p53-1` and you are trying to plot them together by preserving the order).

Let's simply merge df1 and df2 first (I named `TIIIh` and so on as `id` for merge key):

```
combi = pd.merge(ts86, l97, on='id', how='left')
combi = combi.set_index('id')
```

And then, plot each column and show all xticks:

```
ax = combi['Gene_x'].plot(kind='area', figsize=(10, 3))
combi['Gene_y'].plot(kind='area', figsize=(10, 3))
ax.set_xticks(range(combi.shape[0]))
ax.set_xticklabels(combi.index, rotation=90)
```

Now you get this:

[image]

Hope this helps.